# How to combine several excel workbooks into a single book

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have several, multi-sheet workbooks which I would like to combine so that I can search them all simultaneously. So, the merged workbook will contain tabs 1,2,3, of the first workbook, then tabs 1,2,3 of the next workbook.

I know nothing about programming VBA or macros or anything like that. I would be really grateful if someone could give me a script and tell me exactly how to modify it.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: How many is several? For about 10 or so, it's easy enough to do manually, just select all sheets and right-click, move or copy to new workbook.

Answer (score 0):

[Download](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winfiles/RDBMerge.zip) the [RDBMerge Add-in](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm). This would be the best way to accomplish it.

Download and put it somewhere you can find it and enable it in excel. I recommend using the default add-in location at `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\Microsoft\AddIns\`

> Click on File, click on
>   Options, click the Add-ins tab. In the Manage drop-down, choose Excel
>   Add-ins, and click Go. Use “Browse” to go to the add-in and then click
>   on OK. Verify RDBMerge is checked in the add-in list and then click
>   OK.

Then in excel you'll find a button on the ribbon for it, click it and follow the directions.

---

Or with VBA

```
Sub CopyBooks()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Set destinationWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Const path As String = "C:\path\to\"
    Dim file As Variant

    Dim currentSheets As Long
    currentSheets = destinationWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    file = Dir(path & "*.xl*")

    While file <> ""
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(path & file)
            For Each sourceWorksheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
                sourceWorksheet.Copy after:=destinationWorkbook.Worksheets(currentSheets)
                currentSheets = currentSheets + 1
            Next
            sourceWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
            file = Dir
    Wend

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```